# Using CRTP to separate platform specific code

Tags: c++, crtp

I recently got this idea to separate different platform specific implementations (could be Win32/X, opengl/dx/vulkan, etc...) using CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern): I thought of something like this:

**IDisplayDevice.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "OSConfig.h"

namespace cbn
{

    template <class TDerived> // Win32 type here
    struct IDisplayDevice
    {
        bool run_frame(void) {
            return
                static_cast<const TDerived*>(this)->run_frame();
        }
        // a lot of other methods ...       
    };
}
```

**Win32DisplayDevice.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "OSConfig.h"
 // make sure it only gets compiled on win32/64
#if defined(CBN_OS_WINDOWS)

namespace cbn
{
    class CWin32DisplayDevice 
      : public IDisplayDevice<CWin32DisplayDevice> {
    public:
        bool run_frame(void) {  
            call_hInstance();
            call_hWnd();
            #ifdef CBN_RENDERAPI_DX11
            call_dx11_bufferswap();
            #endif
            return some_state; 
        }
    private:
    };
}
#endif
```

I would then provide an other implementation the same way in **XDisplayDevice.h**.
Finally, I would make a common interface in **DisplayDevice.h**:

```
#include "Win32DisplayDevice.h"
#include "XDisplayDevice.h"

namespace cbn
{
    class CDisplayDevice
    {
    public:
        CBN_INLINE 
        bool run_frame(void) { return device_->run_frame(); }
    private:
#if defined(CBN_OS_WINDOWS)
        CWin32DisplayDevice device_;
#elif defined(CBN_OS_LINUX)
        CXDisplayDevice device_;
#elif // and so on
#else
        // does nothing ...
        CNillDisplayDevice device_;
#endif
    }
}
```

So I could call it in **main.cpp** like:

```
int main()
{
    CDisplayDevice my_device;
    while(my_device->run_frame())
    {
        do_some_magic();
    }
}
```

Do you think this would be a good way to deal with platform specific code ?

PS: I avoid victuals and polymorphism because of platform restraints (android, ps4, etc...) where pointer calls matter.

Comment: To make use of the CRTP, you need to derive from `IDisplayDevice`.

Comment: How much _do_ they matter (pointer calls through vtables)? Do you have a concrete limitation or requirement?

Comment: oops; sorry; i wrote that code just now (wasn't copy pasted) :)

Comment: @utnapistim yes; virtuals matter; we're talking about a realtime graphics app here

Comment: It doesn't look like you need IDisplayDevice at all. It is not used anywhere (it is inherited from but then the base class is unused). Why do you think you need CRTP?

Comment: @coder32, can you simply make a traits-like class for the system-specific primitives? (no CRTP involved)

Comment: @utnapistim could you give and example pls ? Maybe as an answer, so I could accept it :)

Comment: @ n.m. Could be used for parameter checking (invalid string, etc...) in other functions

Comment: @Coder32 do you plan (ever) to allow for example Windows users to freely choose DirectX or OpenGL engine? even at runtime?

Comment: @mrtnj there are two executables packaged in the app: for dx11 and ogl; if i want to compile with ogl, I just define CBN_RENDERAPI_OPENGL; but opengl is terrible on windows anyway; you can rely on it %50 of the time;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
struct OpenGLTraits // keep this in it's own files (.h and .cpp)
{
    bool run_frame() { /* open gl specific stuff here */ }
};


struct VulkanTraits // keep this in it's own files (.h and .cpp)
{
    bool run_frame() { /* vulkan specific stuff here */ }
};

template<typename T>
class DisplayDevice
{
    using graphic_traits = T;
    graphic_traits graphics; // maybe inject this in constructor?

    void do_your_operation()
    {
        if(!graphics.run_frame()) // subsystem-specific call
        { ... }
    }
};
```

This will use subsystem-specific calls, and abstract them away between a common API, without a virtual call involved. You can even inline the `run_frame()` implementations.

**Edit** (address comment question):

consider this:

```
#ifdef FLAG_SPECIFYING_OPEN_GL
using Device = DisplayDevice<OpenGLTraits>;
#elif FLAG_SPECIFYING_VULKAN
using Device = DisplayDevice<VulkanTraits>;
...
#endif
```

client code:

```
Device device;
device.do_your_operation();
```

Comment: I really like the traits way of doing it though; really elegant;

Comment: sry for the stupid question; but platform is decided at compile time; would you typedef DisplayDevice ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `using graphic_traits = T`? Couldn't you just call the template parameter `graphic_traits` directly, without the `using`?

Comment: Yes, I could have. I usually add `using` statements and abstract my types based on what roles they play within the class API. Some reasons: in the code I write, template parameters are CamelCase but types are snake_case (this makes a `Device::graphics_traits` type available to client code, not a `Device::GraphicsTraits`; It allows for abstracting away the type while thinking of your API, and to change it in a single place during implementation (e.g. "I think I should expose a `graphics_traits&`, not a `const graphics_traits&` to the client;" which translates to changing a single line of code).

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see the benefit of CRTP here, you still have platform specific (as opposed to feature specific) ifdefs within the code, and this tends to make things harder to read and maintain. I usually prefer having different implementations in different source files - and in fact, generally having seperate directories for each platform.

such as:

- platform/win64
- platform/win32
- platform/gnu-linux
- platform/freebsd

In this way you can largely avoid the ifdef clutter, and you generally know where to find the platform specific things. You also know what you need to write in order to port things to another platform. The build system can then be made to select the correct source rather than the preprocessor.

Comment: btw by different implementations you mean one .h and multiple .cpp-s ?

Comment: and about the build system; do you think it could be done in cmake ?

Comment: ok; so it goes like I have my class deceleration in DisplayDevice.h and then I implement everything in Win32/DisplayTraits.cpp, Linux/DisplayTraits.cpp, etc... and the build system chooses the appropriate cpp at buildtime, right ?

Comment: You have the right idea. CRTP isn't going to help you here becuase you won't have all the platform specific headers or libraries on each platform, so you must use your build system to select the correct platform specific files, and you have to implement this yourself, i.e set your include path, and the specific .cpp files to build for each platform. You can build up a skeleton directory structure of this to see how it might work.  I have used Scons in the past, but you should make your own decision on the build tool or tool(s) and you might decide to use different ones on each platform.

Comment: thx I switched to waf recently from cmake, which isn't c++ or c specific; it allows to defined macros though, and is not as obscure as cmake; i think it would be the right tool for the job, wouldn't it ? PS: why don't you use waf instead of scons ?